# angular-cli: Use different templates depending on the environment

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli

I'm using **@angular/cli: 1.0.0** and I want to use component templates depending on the environment. I've already implemented this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'tbe',
  templateUrl: environment.BASE_TEMPLATE_PATH+'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  ...
}
```

My environment setting looks like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  BASE_TEMPLATE_PATH: '../templates/default/'
};
```

The building process actually works but the browser console throws an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module "."
```

If I replace **environment.BASE_TEMPLATE_PATH+'app.component.html'** with the actual path, it works.

Is it possible to use environment variables here? If yes, where is my mistake?

---

**UPDATE:**

I found a better solution for my problem: http://www.smartjava.org/content/dynamic-component-loading-angular2-replace-compile

I've changed the plunker example to set a templateUrl instead of the plain html template and this works: https://plnkr.co/edit/tfxl3ba869oFtrqzyLNk

***The Problem:***

ComponentResolver is depreciated and I can't use it with the current Angular4 version. I tried it with **ComponentFactoryResolver** but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you really need to have multiple template files for the component? You could consider moving the condition to the template itself (*ngIf), so the component would have a static name of the template file.

Comment: @Ján Halaša Some templates are really different to the default templates. We have multiple clients with the same core functionality but different templates and styles. For better maintaining and smaller client versions of the app, it would be better to have different templates per environment.

Comment: I did a big work around in the cleanest way possible to have templating in the project I currently work on, had that error before and I don't think you can put variables into the decorators. Have you tried calling a function? do a small test, declare a function outside, export function.... and then, call it within the decorator... templateUrl: functionTest(), I think I did sth like that and worked once...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue before, the reason it's complaining is that the path obtained from the `environment.ts` file becomes relative to `environment.ts` file and **NOT** the `AppComponent.ts` as you'd expect.

Try

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  BASE_TEMPLATE_PATH: 'absolute/path/to/template/file'
};
```

and see if it works.

For a better solution, you'll have to write a function that can accurately give the **absolute** path to the template file.

This is a really ugly, hack-ish way of doing it, but it seems like you understand the risk here.

Answer (score 0):

What also would work (at least in the latest Version of Angular) would be

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

const env = environment;

@Component({
  selector: 'tbe',
  templateUrl: env.BASE_TEMPLATE_PATH+'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
  ...
}
```

I am facing the same task so I fiddles around. I also can confirm, that the other files are not included in your AOT-build.