# How can I internationalize a Website written in Angular?

Tags: angular, internationalization, transloco

I need a little help. I'm working on a Website. On this Website, there are Areas with a large amount of text. For example, a story. How can I Internationalize this?

For small texts, like a navigation, I can use modules like transloco. But in my opinion, it's a bad way to put a text with 2,000 Words in a json file. It makes everything confusing and not really maintainable. So what's the way?

Is it somehow possible just to change the html template (templateUrl), that will be loaded by the component?

Comment: The answer is a little old but I'm pretty sure it still holds. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229884/how-to-change-templateurl-value-dynamically-at-run-time-in-angular-2